# Maven: How to add custom classpath entry for plugin execution?

Tags: maven-2, log4j, classpath, maven-plugin, soapui

**UPDATE**: It seems to be SoapUI maven plugin specific issue at first, but it's not, really, so please read through.

I'm running SoapUI plugin with Maven2 like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>eviware</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <settingsFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/soapui-settings.xml</settingsFile>
        <projectFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/my-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
        <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/soapui-output</outputFolder>
        <printReport>true</printReport>
        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
        <exportAll>true</exportAll>
        <soapuiProperties>
        <property>
          <name>soapui.logroot</name>
          <value>${project.build.directory}/soapui-logs/</value>
        </property>
        </soapuiProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It works perfectly and puts all soapui log files into `${project.build.directory}/soapui-logs/` with one exception: `global-groovy.log` which goes into basedir (seems to be bug in SoapUI log4j configuration).

I need an option to override `soapui-log4j.xml` file that comes with SoapUi maven plugin and fix `GLOBAL_GROOVY_LOG` appender from:

```
<param name="File" value="global-groovy.log"/>
```

to this:

```
<param name="File" value="${soapui.logroot}global-groovy.log"/>
```

In the past I ran SoapUI test programmatically from JUnit test and just placed updated `soapui-log4j.xml` file into `src/test/resources/com/eviware/soapui/resources/conf/soapui-log4j.xml` and it worked. Maven copies it into `target/test-classes` and adds that path to `classpath` to run unit tests.

Now the problem with SoapUI maven plugin is that I don't know how to add `src/test/resources/com/eviware/soapui/resources/conf/soapui-log4j.xml` to plugin's `classpath`. Is there anything similar to Surefire's `additionalClasspathElements` [configuration option](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/additional-classpath.html)?

So in other words I want to know how to add additional class path entries to any generic maven plugin execution environment, not only SoapUI plugin.

Comment: I've also seen soapui.log and soapui-errors.log placed in basedir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to add to a plugins dependencies using the [*dependencies*](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.2/maven-model/maven.html#class_plugin) element. From the POM reference:

> Additional dependencies that this project needs to introduce to the plugin's classloader.

I don't know how maven treats these dependencies, so it might place them after the plugin's own classes which effectively prevents overriding the log4j configuration, but give it a try; package the log4j configuration file in a jar and add it as a dependency to the plugin.